# pdb skipped one hidden frame issue

Tags: python, ipython, pdb

Whenever I try to run the program in a ipython cell it gives me a weird error.

```py
test_pts = sorted_points
new_segments = []
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
for i in range(0, len(test_pts)-1):
    x1 = test_pts[i][0]; y1 = test_pts[i][1]; x2 = test_pts[i][2]; y2 = test_pts[i][3]; angle1 = test_pts[i][4]
    print(x1, y1, x2, y2, angle1)
    for j in range(i + 1, len(test_pts)):
        n_x1 = test_pts[j][0]; n_y1 = test_pts[j][1]; n_x2 = test_pts[j][2]; n_y2 = test_pts[j][3]; angle2 = test_pts[j][4]
        if (isclose(angle1, angle2, rel_tol = 1)) and (isclose(x1, x2, rel_tol = 1) and (isclose(y1, y1, rel_tol = 1))):
            
            print(n_x1, n_y1, n_x2, n_y2, angle2) 
            break
```

The stack trace below -> I feel like this problem is not reproducible, and it is not even code-specific, i.e there is nothing wrong with the code I have written, but I'm unable to figure out what is causing this behaviour.

```
# %% LINE EXTENSION - CONNECT...
--Return--
None
> (3)()
      1 test_pts = sorted_points
      2 new_segments = []
----> 3 import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
      4 for i in range(0, len(test_pts)-1):
      5     x1 = test_pts[i][0]; y1 = test_pts[i][1]; x2 = test_pts[i][2]; y2 = test_pts[i][3]; angle1 = test_pts[i][4]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

> /home/and/CERLAB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py(3346)run_code()
   3344             finally:
   3345                 # Reset our crash handler in place
-> 3346                 sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
   3347         except SystemExit as e:
   3348             if result is not None:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure what the problem exactly is - this isn't something that happens in a normal python file, seems to only happen in .ipnyb files.

The breakpoints put in this manner only work if they are inside a function, otherwise they don't work. So basically if you are running into this problem, then make sure that the statement is inside a function.