# Why does pdb debugger in jupyter notebook trigger "skipped hidden frame" and how to resolve it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython, pdb

I am trying to use the `breakpoint()` or `pdb.set_trace()` debugger in a cell in the Jupyter Notebook:

```
a=1
b=1
breakpoint()
c=1
d=1
```

`ipdb` could let the `breakpoint()` to stop, but when I entered `n` to run the next line, the following shows up:

```
ipdb> n
    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

> /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py(3435)run_ast_nodes()
   3433                     to_run.append((node, 'single'))
   3434 
-> 3435                 for node,mode in to_run:
   3436                     if mode == 'exec':
   3437                         mod = Module([node], [])
```

Normally the line `c=1` will be executed, but I do not know why this occurs.
I am certain that such a breakpoint works fine on my previous linux machine.

My question echoes [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050902/pdb-skipped-one-hidden-frame-issue).

Answer (score 0):

My answer from here -
[pdb skipped one hidden frame issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050902/pdb-skipped-one-hidden-frame-issue)

I don't know what the issue is, but it seems like the pdb breakpoint only works if its within a function. I think it's something to do with how the interpreter works in python notebooks.